# Using extension methods in architecture

Tags: c#, architecture, f#, extension-methods, c#-to-f#

Is there any problem with performance, memory, security ,etc. in using of extension methods?

and I want to use extension methods vastly in my architecture,

make a functions layer(in F# that works with data) that will be used by the main application layer(in C#) that F# extension methods will be called on dbcontext instances like `context.doSomething();` and by the way don't instanciating services(classes) when want to use them instead using them as extension methods

does it matters?

Comment: ... as opposed to what? The thing is that "performance issues" are always relative. If there is only 1 way to do things, and you're already doing it optimally, then you have 2 choices; 1) do it, 2) don't do it. However, if you have alternatives, you need to compare to that instead. So what exactly are you comparing it against? Is there a reason you want to go for extension methods instead of instance methods?

Comment: Also know that your question is highly subjective. Is this a *good* way of doing things? Can I do *better*? What my opinion on those questions might be, someone else might have a completely different opinion, and as such your question is highly likely to be closed as "Primarily based on opinion". Can you rewrite your question to be less based on someones opinion?

Comment: Why would you think extension methods affect performance? The logic in your method is what matters.

Comment: Well a service class gets instantiated by using new keyword but what about an extension method is it exist in memory alongside with application or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any problem with

Let's see....

> performance

No, this is syntactic sugar to a static method call. No difference.

> memory

Did I say static method call, with a this pointer. No difference.

> security

Static method call with a this pointer. No difference. Standard security applies.

THAT SAID...

> etc

There are a couple of possible issues with extension methods.

First, you are bound to overload your DbContext with hundreds of extension methods. This looses the ability to actually make some sort of logical grouping. People will get confused, and possibly also even get confused on where a specific method comes from.

Second, you successfully torpedo the use of inheritance and dependency injection. Extension methods are essentially static methods, so they can not be abstract and overwritten, and there is no constructor on an instance to call dependency injection.

As base of an architecture I would be extremely careful - you possibly successfully torpedo everything that makes a good architecture. This depends on the exact use case, obviously.

Comment: mm... you're right, that wasn't a good way, thank you

Comment: I generally use them to extend code - i.e. my DAL code is completely generated. But this means calls to stored procedures do not use ennums, which are not even defined in the dal project. So, an extension method makes sure I can call a stored procedure with "type safe" parameters.

Comment: I did this exact thing in a prior job.  It wasn't hundreds of extension methods (though the folks who made Linq never thought that was a problem); it was more like a dozen, but it worked quite well.  Inheritance is overrated; dependency injection is only needed if you require dependencies.

Comment: I think it will make sense if I make my services generic; but there are already too many overloads on DbContext and it will be a little confusing

Answer (score 2):

An extension method

```
var newString = myString.DoSomething();
```

is just syntactic sugar over

```
var myString = StringHelper.DoSomething(myString);
```

So treat extension methods with the same considerations as you would any other `static` method.  Performance, security, memory usage should all be identical.